# Comprehensive tutorial on Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, documentation, pyinstaller

I'm looking for a tutorial on [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) that will explain things like

- how to create .pkg files
- how to include/exclude modules
- how to include data files inside the install directory.

I cannot make much sense out of the [standard PyInstaller documentation](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/trunk/doc/Manual.html?format=raw).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both guides in the accepted answer seem outdated.
PyInstaller now provides an executable script that allows you to do

```
pyinstaller your_script.py
```

wherever `your_script.py` is located - instead of the old mode of copying your `your_script.py` to wherever you copied the source code of PyInstaller.

Here's a brief, more recent guide that walks you through a simple Hello World example:

http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/

Comment: The newest version of pyinstaller (2.1) is pretty neat. Check out the official [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/). It's very easy to understand and covers all the uses.

Answer (score 15):

Have you looked here: [simplified tutorial](http://excid3.com/blog/pyinstaller-a-simple-tutorial/)

Or here: [a bit longer tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/)

EDIT: Adding data files is implied in the second tutorial.  If you use the second example just before the "Wrapping Up" section, along with the official documentation: [Analysis](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/tags/1.4/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#analysis), it looks like you'd specify your data-file dependencies as part of the "datas" subobject when calling the Analysis() function.

EDIT2: From official documentation: "Generally, you will not need to create your own PKGs, as the EXE will do it for you. This is one way to include read-only data in a single-file deployment, however. A single-file deployment including TK support will use this technique."

Example (should be roughly like this):

```
a = Analysis(...)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
pkg = PKG(a.pure, name="PackageName")
exe = EXE(pyz, pkg,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          ...)
```

Comment: I see your 2nd link talks about including additional modules. What about the other items I mention, or did I miss those somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's implied in the second tutorial, if you use this along with the official documentation--edited answer with the details that were in this edit (for continuity).

Comment: Both guides in the accepted answer seem outdated, and Pyinstaller now provides different API.

Answer (score 2):

**To Create one executable of your python script or project**
create your script or project. **To install pyinstaller on Windows type**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Now open command prompt and type the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscripy.py
```

You will find a dist folder created. Browse dist folder and you will get .exe file of python script.