# csv.writer returning strange results

Tags: python, csv

my code looks like this:

```
import csv

mesta=["Ljubljana","Kranj","Skofja Loka","Trzin"]
opis=["ti","mene","ti mene","ne ti mene"]
delodajalci=["GENI","MOJEDELO","MOJADELNICA","HSE"]
ime=["domen","maja","andraz","sanja"]
datum=["2.1.2014","5.10.2014","11.12.2014","5.5.2014"]

with open('sth.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    zapis = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    dolzina=len(datum)
    i=0
    while i<dolzina:
        zapis.writerows([ime[i]+","+delodajalci[i]+","+opis[i]+","+datum[i]+","+mesta[i]])
        i+=1
```

and for some strange reason my result looks like:
d o m e n    G E N I     t i     2 . 1 . 2 0 1 4     L j u b l j a n a
m a j a      M O J E D E L O     m e n e     5 . 1 0 . 2 0 1 4   K r a n j
a n d r a z      M O J A D E L N I C A   t i " " m e n e     1 1 . 1 2 . 2 0 1 4     S k o f j a " " L o k a
s a n j a    H S E   n e " " t i " " m e n e     5 . 5 . 2 0 1 4     T r z i n

So a 4 rows x 5 column table.

I would like advice on how to make these white spaces and " " go away. So that for instance d o m e n would be domen and S k o f j a " " L o k a, Skofja Loka.
I would be forever grateful for your help. Oh and if it is possibile to do it without any other modules that'd be even better since I have a problem installing them on this computer aswell :(

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

mesta=["Ljubljana","Kranj","Skofja Loka","Trzin"]
opis=["ti","mene","ti mene","ne ti mene"]
delodajalci=["GENI","MOJEDELO","MOJADELNICA","HSE"]
ime=["domen","maja","andraz","sanja"]
datum=["2.1.2014","5.10.2014","11.12.2014","5.5.2014"]

with open('sth.csv','w') as csvfile:
    zapis = csv.writer(csvfile)
    zapis.writerows(zip(ime,delodajalci,opis,datum,mesta))
```

creates the output:

> domen,GENI,ti,2.1.2014,Ljubljana
>
> maja,MOJEDELO,mene,5.10.2014,Kranj
>
> andraz,MOJADELNICA,ti mene,11.12.2014,Skofja Loka
>
> sanja,HSE,ne ti mene,5.5.2014,Trzin

In what you had, writerows was getting a single string (including commas between what you wanted).  You wanted it to just print that string out.  But the csvwriter wants to print a list with a separator between entries.  It only had a string, so when it treats that as a list, each character gets printed, then the separator.

In what I've done, I've got writerows receiving a bunch of lists.  Each list comes from `zip`, so each list consists of the 'i'th entries of the arguments zip got.

**edit** removed dolzina and i=0 since not needed anymore.

Comment: Oh and maybe you know, does there exist any py to exe converter, because I'm having trouble converting it with py2exe and cmd.
Thank you again by the way.

Comment: I don't know about creating .exe, but you might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592913/how-do-i-convert-a-python-program-to-a-runnable-exe-windows-program .

Comment: And if by chance I would like every piece of data to be in it's own cell, I would have to add what? Since now I get an output of:
domen,GENI,ti,2.1.2014,Ljubljana

maja,MOJEDELO,mene,5.10.2014,Kranj

andraz,MOJADELNICA,ti mene,11.12.2014,Skofja Loka

sanja,HSE,ne ti mene,5.5.2014,Trzin
But one line of output is writen in 1 cell. So basically this kind of output fills A1:A4 in my excel file and I would like to it fill A1:D4. Any simple changes I could make?

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more explanation of what you're seeing.  When I run exactly this code it fills A1 through E4