# Converting a python 3.5.2 file with images to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, animated-gif

I really need some help with a project. Can you help me convert a tkinter python 3.5 file, which contains images (.gif) to .exe? Any help would be usefull! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i convert a Python program to a runnable .exe Windows program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592913/how-do-i-convert-a-python-program-to-a-runnable-exe-windows-program)

Comment: I think a important distinction is that the program has external image files which might not get rolled into the .exe easily. I believe because of that, this question is not a duplicate.