# How to create .exe file from python script

Tags: python, exe, launcher

I have an python script which initializes spring boot web service and executes an java application and creates windows task scheduler, I want this script to converted into exe.
I tried converting to exe using pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe, also I have tried wrapping this python launch in bat file and converted that to exe using bat-to-exe converter, but for all these solutions antivirus detects the exe as threat.
Can some one please let me know, what is the best possible and proper way to create exe from a python file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent exe created by pyinstaller from being deleted by Antivirus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907339/how-to-prevent-exe-created-by-pyinstaller-from-being-deleted-by-antivirus)

Comment: If you're using AVG AntiVirus, https://www.avg.com/en-us/false-positive-file-form — you should get a response fairly quickly along with updated virus definitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)