# How to include description, version, author in python exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, compilation, version, pyinstaller, executable

I am trying to make an executable file for some python script. This application is a console level application which uses parameters for execution.

I have compiled and did build the executable (exe) file using pyinstaller. The exe file is build successfully and running fine.

However now I want to include the **version, author name and description** for this **executable** file, I searched for multiple options but don't seem to find a solution.

Any help or references would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a macos application, you can put the version in the `app` section of the spec file, and then build with `pyinstaller name.spec`.

See the [documentation here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-macos-bundle).

I don't know about other platforms, and I'd also like to know how to set the author and other metadata (eg email address).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways,
depend on what tools you use to make your package or executable

you can use the .spec file,
but the wiki doesn't have the proper documentation about the usage,
and if your script is also a package, it wont work properly
and has a very low access

or

Is more clear, and user frendly creating a version.txt with the version wroted inside, and you can access it from any script you need

when you're creating your .exe , you can add to the shell(DOS) command:

```
# the <> obviously are not required
pyinstaller <scriptName>.py --version-file <fileVersionName>.txt <other options..>
```

and then add a refence to .txt file in the spec* if you are running...

```
pyinstaller <fileVersionName>.spec ...
```

*more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py)

here's the [pyinstaller wiki](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#capturing-windows-version-data):

Or doing it how the accepted answer says in this
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879713/pyinstaller-2-0-how-to-add-descriptions-for-a-windows-exe-file)

MOST USEFULL WIKI: [setuptools documentation\quickstart](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#basic-use)