# How to make windows standalone exe for python flask/jinja/sqlite application

Tags: python, flask

There are a bunch of tools out there like pyInstaller, py2exe, etc. But none of them seems to work while making a Windows standalone executable for a Flask application.

Can someone guide me with proper instructions as to how one can create executable for a Flask application? I want to distribute the application as single clickable exe for end users.

To be specific, the application has following dependencies.
- Flask
- Sqlalchemy
- Requests
- Httplib2
- Database used is SQLite

I don't want to open the code as of now, but if someone has a good solution, I can send the project repo privately for testing purposes.

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all since python project with flask are known for having own specific methods for being converted into standalone executable

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create a standalone executable for a flask app in windows, you should use `docker` in order to containerize/package your flask app (if it must be packaged).

`Docker` will give you something that is system agnostic, is well understood to work, and is in line with best practices.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into docker. Just one question. Can I make a standalone using Docker? I want to distribute the application to end users and not to developers. So I want to give a single clickable exe file to them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using pyinstaller that creates one executable of your python project:
for more info you can refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140662/5114581

official website:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: I know about pyInstaller, and I was able to work on it too on simple python files. But it seems to fail in case of Flask projects. Have you tried this with Flask?