# How to compile multiple python files into single .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created a GUI (using Tkinter) in python and this runs python files on click of a button from GUI using os.system('python_file.py'). I wanted to bundle all these python files into single .exe file using pyinstaller by keeping the Tkinter file as main.

I created the .exe file by doing the following in command line:

pyinstaller --debug --onefile --noupx tkinter_app.py

Currently my .spec file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['tkinter_app.py'],pathex=['C:\\test'],binaries=[],datas=[],
hiddenimports=[],hookspath=[],runtime_hooks=[],excludes=[], win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
win_private_assemblies=False, cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, a.datas, name='tkinter_app', debug=True, strip=False, upx=False,console=True )
```

**I'm not sure how to include the other python files in the above .spec file so that the whole application works**. Can someone please help?

Comment: You can follow this steps:https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140662/5114581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the array **datas**

For example like this:

```
a = Analysis(['.\\main.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[ ('.\\Ressources\\i18n', 'i18n'),
             ('.\\Ressources\\file1.py', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

Note: Make sure to put it in the right relative path so your program will be able to access it

Edit: Given your error message, the problem is not in packaging with PyInstaller but in os.system command.

os.system is equivalent to opening a DOS command window and typping your command *python_file.py*

To access your python files, you have to know:

- PyInstaller unpack your packed files in a temporary folder that you can access in sys._MEIPASS (only works from the .exe)
- os.system can be used to launch python given the complete path to the file like this:
  `os.system("python " + os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "python_file.py"))`

  But be carefull, this will only work if python is installed on the system (and included in syspath) and from the exe. Executing directly your python file will send exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not able to run the supporting python files from GUI by making the changes suggested. I get a error like  'file1.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. SPEC FILE: a = Analysis(['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\tkinter_app.py'], pathex=['.'], binaries=None, datas=[('C:\\Python27\\Tools\\i18n','i18n'), ('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\file1.py','.'),
('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\file2.py','.'), ('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\file3.py','.'),
('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\file4.py','.'), ('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\file5.py','.'), .....

Comment: This works perfectly when python is installed in my computer. How can we run this application in computers where python is not installed?

Comment: pack your python_file.py script into a function (called python_file() for example) and call it from your main script instead of os.system.

Comment: How do I include python libraries (numpy, pandas) when compiling using pyinstaller. As i'm running supporting python files using os.system, the libraries in these files are not being included in the exe file

Comment: hiddenimports=[] is the key

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have two files: **"my_main.py"** and **"my_functions.py"**.  Assume that **"my_main.py"** imports methods from **"my_functions.py"**

Execute the following command:

> pyinstaller --onefile my_main.py my_functions.py

Resulting single executable file **"my_main.exe"** will be created under **"dist"** folder of present working directory.

Identical process for Linux/Windows. For more than two python files just include them one after separated by space.

> pyinstaller --onefile my_main.py my_functions.py file3.py file4.py

Answer (score 0):

- Not fully validated, maybe useful for your reference.
- Background: I have use several time `PyInstaller` in Win and Mac.
- Answer for your question:

  - `pyinstaller --onefile tkinter_app.py python_file.py`
- Extra Explanation: If `main.py` import `some_other.py` (and/or some other libs, such as above someone mentioned `numpy`, `pandas`, etc ..., then `PyInstaller` can auto recognize it, do not need add `--onefile` and other py file, just need

  - `pyinstaller main.py`
- You should refer [official doc](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) if expect detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

open auto-py-to-exe in your command prompt.

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

if you don't already have it installed you can do so using

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

then open it.

[auto-py-to-exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXZyg.png)

confirm whether you want it console-based or not then convert