# Converting two linked python files to one single exe file

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a way where I can convert my two python scripts which are linked together to a single executable file. I can make that two scripts to a single script and convert but i just want to know is there a way to convert multiple python files to one exe. Hope I ll get a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile multiple python files into single .exe file using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183137/how-to-compile-multiple-python-files-into-single-exe-file-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: Thanks,,,That really helped me.