# How to compile multiple subprocess python files into single .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-standalone

I have a similar question to this one:[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183137/how-to-compile-multiple-python-files-into-single-exe-file-using-pyinstaller).
I have a GUI and where the user can input information and the other scripts use some of that information to run.I have 4 different scripts for each button. I run them as a subprocess so that the main gui doesn’t act up or say that it’s not responding. This is an example of what I have since the code is really long since I used PAGE to generate the gui.

```
###Main.py#####
import subprocess

def resource_path(relative_path):
    #I got this from another post to include images but I'm also using it to include the scripts"
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
Class aclass:
    def get_info(self):
        global ModelNumber, Serial,SpecFile,dateprint,Oper,outputfolder
        ModelNumber=self.Model.get()
        Serial=self.SerialNumber.get()
        outputfolder=self.TEntry2.get()
        SpecFile= self.Spec_File.get()

        return ModelNumber,Serial,SpecFile,outputfolder

    def First(self):
        aclass.get_info(self)                          #Where I use the resource path function
        First_proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, resource_path('first.py'),str(ModelNumber),str(Serial),str(path),str(outputfolder)])
        First_proc.wait()


#####First.py#####
import numpy as np
import scipy 
from main import aclass

ModelNumber    = sys.argv[1]
Serial         = sys.argv[2]
path           = sys.argv[3]
path_save      = sys.argv[4]
```

and this goes on for my second,third, and fourth scripts.

In my spec file, I added:

```
a.datas +=[('first.py','C\\path\\to\\script\\first.py','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('main.py','C\\path\\to\\script\\main.py','DATA')]
```

this compiles and it works, but when I try to convert it to an .exe, it crashes because it can't import first.py properly and its own libraries (numpy,scipy....etc). I've tried adding it to the a.datas, and runtime_hooks=['first.py'] in the spec file...and I can't get it to work. Any ideas? I'm not sure if it's giving me this error because it is a subprocess.

Comment: why not build first.py into an exe as well and then use subprocess to open that exe?  bundling an exe that then calls python seems like a broken way to do it (as an additional aside i have found it to be problematic to not have the bundled path the same as the dist path ) (is `a.datas += [('assets/my_file.txt','assets/my_file.txt','DATA'),]`)

Comment: If you really want to do this, the easiest way is probably to create an `entrypoint` script that reads `sys.argv[1]` and dispatches on that to `import` a different module (`main`, or `first`, or `second`, etc.) and call a method out of it. Then, `main` doesn't try to subprocess `first.py`, it instead subprocesses `entrypoint` with `first` as an extra argument.

Comment: @abarnert do you have an example of what an entrypoint script might look like? I just make basic scripts. Nothing too advanced

Comment: @MoeAvera I tried to show how to do it without anything too advanced in my answer—it adds a _bit_ more work, but compared to trying to teach you advanced `setuptools` features, I think it saves a lot of time for both of us. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't restructure your app so this isn't necessary (e.g., by using `multiprocessing` instead of `subprocess`), there are three solutions:

- Ensure that the .exe contains the scripts as an (executable) zipfile—or just use `pkg_resources`—and copy the script out to a temporary directory so you can run it from there.
- Write a multi-entrypoint wrapper script that can be run as your main program, and also run as each script—because, while you can't *run a script* out of the packed exe, you can *import a module* out of it.
- Using `pkg_resources` again, write a wrapper that runs the script by loading it as a string and running it with `exec` instead.

The second one is probably the cleanest, but it *is* a bit of work. And, while we could rely on [`setuptools` entrypoints](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) to some of the work, trying to explain how to do this is much harder than explaining how to do it manually,<sup>1</sup> so I'm going to do the latter.

---

Let's say your code looked like this:

```
# main.py
import subprocess
import sys
spam, eggs = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'vikings.py', spam])
subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'waitress.py', spam, eggs])

# vikings.py
import sys
print(' '.join(['spam'] * int(sys.argv[1])))

# waitress.py
import sys
import time
spam, eggs = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
if eggs > spam:
    print("You can't have more eggs than spam!")
    sys.exit(2)
print("Frying...")
time.sleep(2)
raise Exception("This sketch is getting too silly!")
```

So, you run it like this:

```
$ python3 main.py 3 4
spam spam spam
You can't have more eggs than spam!
```

---

We want to reorganize it so there's a script that looks at the command-line arguments to decide what to import. Here's the smallest change to do that:

```
# main.py
import subprocess
import sys
if sys.argv[1][:2] == '--':
    script = sys.argv[1][2:]
    if script == 'vikings':
        import vikings
        vikings.run(*sys.argv[2:])
    elif script == 'waitress':
        import waitress
        waitress.run(*sys.argv[2:])
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Unknown script {script}')
else:
    spam, eggs = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, __file__, '--vikings', spam])
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, __file__, '--waitress', spam, eggs])

# vikings.py
def run(spam):
    print(' '.join(['spam'] * int(spam)))

# waitress.py
import sys
import time
def run(spam, eggs):
    spam, eggs = int(spam), int(eggs)
    if eggs > spam:
        print("You can't have more eggs than spam!")
        sys.exit(2)
    print("Frying...")
    time.sleep(2)
    raise Exception("This sketch is getting too silly!")
```

And now:

```
$ python3 main.py 3 4
spam spam spam
You can't have more eggs than spam!
```

---

A few changes you might want to consider in real life:

- DRY: We have the same three lines of code copied and pasted for each script, and we have to type each script name three times. You can just use something like `__import__(sys.argv[1][2:]).run(sys.argv[2:])` with appropriate error handling.
- Use `argparse` instead of this hacky special casing for the first argument. If you're already sending non-trivial arguments to the scripts, you're probably already using `argparse` or an alternative anyway.
- Add an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to each script that just calls `run(sys.argv[1:])`, so that during development you can still run the scripts directly to test them.

I didn't do any of these because they'd obscure the idea for this trivial example.

---

<sub>1 The documentation is great as a refresher if you've already done it, but as a tutorial and explanatory rationale, not so much. And trying to write the tutorial that the brilliant PyPA guys haven't been able to come up with for years… that's probably beyond the scope of an SO answer.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much!
This is definitely going to be a learning experience.